# Initializing a std::vector replacement with single curly braces instead of double curly braces

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector, stdinitializerlist

I have a code similar to the following one:

```cpp
namespace mine
{
  template<class T>
  using _vector = std::vector<T, my_allocator<T>>;

  template<class T>
  class myvector : public _vector<T>{};
};
```

This works in most cases as my own std::vector drop-in replacement, but it doesn't quite work at initializing it with a list like with a normal std::vector:

```cpp
#include "myvector.h"

void foo(void)
{
  std::vector<int> vi = { 1, 2, 3 };
  mine::myvector<int> mvi = { { 1, 2, 3 } };
}
```

Notice that I have used double curly braces to compile it. So, what I'm missing here? And, more importantly, what can I do to be able to initialize mine::myvector as I do with a normal std::vector?

Comment: why do you use inheritance? I looks like `myvector` is just `_vector`

Comment: `using myvector = _vector<T>;`

Comment: add `using _vector<T>::_vector;` inside a class to inherit constructors and [problem solved](https://godbolt.org/z/qH6s_x).

Comment: offtopic: underscore prefixed symbols are reserved for compiler.

Comment: Thank you @MarekR! Adding "_vector<T>::_vector" was actually what I was looking for. If you add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @MarekR "underscore prefixed symbols are reserved"  not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your class do not have any constructors defined or inherited.
So for moment I was wondering how your code compiles at all.

Your code uses [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Since you do not have any fields just public inheritance, first argument of aggregate initialization is passed to ancestor. This is reason why you need double braces.

One way to fix it is to [inherit constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors) from base class. So your class looks like this:

```cpp
  template<class T>
  class myvector : public _vector<T>{
      using _vector<T>::_vector;
  };
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qH6s_x

IMO much better solution would be do not define a class but define alias for type:

```cpp
  template<class T>
  using myvector = _vector<T>;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Pt6sRQ